# Encrypt password custom rule in DataMapper and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, passwords, password-encryption, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using Codeigniter 2.0.3 with DataMapper ORM 1.6.0. Integration DataMapper in CI has been implemented successfully and everything works fine, except password encryption.

I have model called `users.php` with class `Users`. I also have set validation rules:

```
var $validation = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'password',
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rules' => array('required', 'trim', 'unique', 'min_length' => 5, 'encrypt'),
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'label' => 'Email Address',
        'rules' => array('required', 'trim', 'valid_email')
    )
);
```

My encrypt function in validation rule:

```
function _encrypt($field)
{
    // Don't encrypt an empty string
    if (!empty($this->{$field}))
    {
        // Generate a random salt if empty
        if (empty($this->salt))
        {
            $this->salt = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        }

        $this->{$field} = sha1($this->salt . $this->{$field});
    }
}
```

MySQL `users` table structure:

```
id
email
password
last_login
created_on
```

I simple create new user via controller:

```
$u = new Users();
$u->email = 'mario1@mario-design.info';
$u->password = 'mario';
$u->save();
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

Full code of `users.php` model [here](http://codepad.org/4zZgbSwb).

---

User successfully stored in the database but with original password not encrypted.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Regards
Mario

Comment: Can we see your full `users.php` model? Your code is correct, so I'm assuming the validation rule can't be found.

Comment: @swatkins I have updated my first post with full `users.php` model code link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved problem with upgrading DataMapper to 1.8.x version. Now, it works just fine!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's that your `salt` class variable is missing. In your `_encrypt` function, you call `$this->salt`, however, you never declare salt in the model. I think you need to add a `salt` variable in the class:

```
// in your Users model
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed.');

class Users extends DataMapper {

    var $table = 'users';
    var $has_one = array('profile');
    var $salt = 'B1471tU77IK1411'; // any string - helps to make password encryption stronger
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I've also tried but without success. The problem still remains..

Comment: Have you tried submitting with an invalid email to test if your validation is being called at all?

Comment: Yes, I checked the email address validation and it works. I solved problem with upgrading DataMapper to 1.8.x version. Now, it works just fine! Thanks..

Comment: You might want to answer this question that you updated and mark that as the accepted answer. That way, this question won't show up in "unanswered" anymore.